# Can't hide UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to have a custom UIButton become hidden once it's pressed a certain number of times...but I'm at a loss.

Having exhausted my limited knowledge and consulting the Apple's documentation as well as the internet for the better part of 3 hours, I've finally made my way here. I've been learning Swift for a short while now and am making an effort to become more familiar with it. This is my first object-oriented language and it's testing me to say the least. Any help with this more likely than not ridiculously simple problem is very much appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var buttonMessageDisplay: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttonPressed()
}

var tapcount = 0

let buttonMessage : [String] = [/* long array of strings */]

func buttonPressed() {

    let button = UIButton(type:.Custom) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 3
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)


    switch tapcount {

    case 19...23:
        //Hides the button
        button.hidden = true
        buttonMessageDisplay.text = buttonMessage[tapcount]

    case 24...31:
        //Unhides the button
        button.hidden = false
        buttonMessageDisplay.text = buttonMessage[tapcount]

    default:
        buttonMessageDisplay.text = buttonMessage[tapcount]
    }

    print("Tap Count: \(tapcount)")
    ++tapcount

}
```

**Updated with Gesture Recognizer:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var buttonMessageDisplay: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    buttonMessageDisplay.text = ""

    let button = UIButton(type:.Custom) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 3
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}


var tapcount : Int = 0

let buttonMessage : [String] = [/* array of strings */]

@IBAction func userTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Tap Received")
    if case 19...23 = tapcount {
        buttonPressed()
    }
}



func buttonPressed() {

    switch tapcount {

    case 0...18:
        buttonMessageDisplay.text = buttonMessage[tapcount]

    case 19...23:
        //Hides the button
        button.hidden = true
        buttonMessageDisplay.text = buttonMessage[tapcount]

    case 24...32:
        //Unhides the button
        button.hidden = false
        buttonMessageDisplay.text = buttonMessage[tapcount]

    case 33...100:
        buttonMessageDisplay.text = buttonMessage[tapcount]

    default:
        print("There are no more messages or an error has been encountered")
    }

    print("Tap Count: \(tapcount)")
    ++tapcount
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain your question in proper way.

Comment: You are creating a new button every time buttonPressed is called. Move the button creation code to viewDidLoad and just have ButtonPressed handle the tap counts and hiding.

Comment: In doing that, how can I affect the button from  within the buttonPressed function?

Comment: Use "buttonPressed:" for your selector (notice the added colon) and change  to `func buttonPressed(button: UIButton) {`.

Comment: by the way, you can't tap a hidden button, so you can't increase taps to "unhide" it.

Comment: @Sulthan, I was about to ask the same thing. What are you trying to achieve? The issue with your code is that you are creating a new button overtime you click the old one, thats why it is not getting hidden the is a stack of buttons. However, if you only get one button you won't be able to unhide it as you can`t click it

Comment: This code has no gesture recognizer.  If you're going to call buttonPressed from a button and a gestureRecognizer, then that changes the situation.

Comment: I've implemented a Gesture Recognizer to solve the hidden button issue. But yeah, I see what you two mean by the the constant button creation. I originally didn't want to hide the button, rather just change its background color to match the whole background, essentially making it "invisible". However I continually had a fine red ring around the white "invisible" button when I used that method. So, in my just fooling around, I tried a few other things, and ended up at this point.

Comment: Rule #1, post your real code.  There is no gestureRecognizer in the above code.  Leave the code you've posted, but update your question with the version with the gestureRecognizer.

Comment: @vacawama Sorry, I added the gesture as soon as the hidden button issue was pointed out and it didn't even occur to me that I was the only one that could see it. Apologies

Comment: Make button a property of the viewController, then you will be able to access it in buttonPressed.  Declare it above viewDidLoad as `let button: UIButton!` and then change `let button = ...` in viewDidLoad to `button = ...`.  Then you can access it as `button` in buttonPressed.

Comment: @vacawama That did it! I appreciate you being so persistent, even though my code is pretty useless and a mess. I've definitely picked up some useful information from this fiasco. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense. As @formal says in his answer, you're creating a new button on every tap, which is wrong.

You want to define your button in your Storyboard.

Then you want an IBAction method, which takes the button as a parameter:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) 
{
  ++tapcount
  if tapcount < 19
  {
    sender.hidden = true
  }
}
```

Note that if the button you're hiding is the same one the user is tapping, once it is hidden, you're done. The user can't tap a hidden button, so there's no way to un-hide it. (And thus no point in your switch statement)

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you are creating a new button every time you call button pressed.  Create an @IBOutlet for your button and just set its hidden property in butPressed (which can be set as an action of the button).

Something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonMessageDisplay: UILabel!

    var tapcount = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    @IBAction func butPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        switch tapcount {

        case 19...23:
            //Hides the button
            button.hidden = true

        case 24...31:
            //Unhides the button
            button.hidden = false

        default: break
        }

        print("Tap Count: \(tapcount)")
        buttonMessageDisplay.text = "Tap: \(tapcount)"

        ++tapcount

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `buttonPressed()` creates a new button each time it is called. You should define `button` as a property similar to `buttonMessageDisplay` and place the code to initialise it within `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score -2):

You should give space between range in case condition:

For example:

```
(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    self.count++;

    switch (self.count) {
        case 5 ... 23 :
            self.button.titleLabel.text = @"disable";
            self.button.hidden = true;

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only a style change which I actually disagree with.